# How to background the application and that application after some time

Tags: android

I Develop a one application which contaion the scenario given below in that 
Some time of application goes into the background and after the some period of time that application comes in front of side this just createing the demo application.

> In this application i can't use any GPS System also.
>
> ```
> please help to solve this problem and which kinds of permision to give
> ```
>
> the  application and how to face this problem.

Thanx in advance

@androidTech

Comment: You are not exaclty defining what is your problem, moving application to background or using GPS.

Comment: in that i want to do some thing application which is in idle mode after few minute that app comes in active mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand, you want to hide your application in background. So, there is a method for that

```
moveTaskToBack(boolean nonRoot)
```

this will do the trick for you, when you pass boolean true to its arguments.